# How to force Windows Server 2016/2019 to check for updates

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, updates, api

I am installing updates using the Windows Update API but the Windows Updates GUI does NOT change the "Last checked date" no matter I just perform a scan or is installing updates. (the Last checked date is now several weeks old, and updates history is showing several was installed within the last day)

usoclient StartScan does NOT make any changes to the Last checked date

Neither does the Powershell command Get-WindowsUpdate from the Module PSWindowsUpdate

In previous Windows I am updating the Last checked value in registry after performing a scan using the API (as they dont). But MS has moved the location to an unknown place i 2016 and 2019.

Anyone who knows how to update the “Last checked date” from CMD or API or ...???

Comment: Have you rebooted the server?

Comment: Yes, this is part of installing the updates

Comment: How about this, `usoclient startinteractivescan`, let the GUI rescan or whatever, and then see if the message changes or if it does something different.